# Creating JWT signing method for AWS key in Go

Tags: go, jwt, amazon-kms

I generated an ECC_NIST_P521 spec key, which uses the ECDSA_SHA_512 signing algorithm. I'm trying to create a `jwt.SigningMethod` with this in mind, but I'm not sure which values to use for the fields. This is what I have so far:

```
signingMethod := jwt.SigningMethodECDSA {
    Name: "ECC_NIST_P521",
    Hash: crypto.SHA512,
}
```

Specifically, I'm not sure if the name is correct and I don't know what to use for the `KeySize` and `CurveBits` fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `Hash`, `CurveBits` and `KeySize`. The value of `Name` is ignored:

```
signingMethod := jwt.SigningMethodECDSA{
        Name:      "ECC_NIST_P521",
        Hash:      crypto.SHA512,
        CurveBits: 521,
        KeySize:   66,
    }
```

521 bits - the size of curve field.

66 - number of bytes that fit a compact representation of a point on the curve.

Full example to sign and verify signature: https://go.dev/play/p/bEnLN2PJv4a

Comment: Doesn't that make it the same as `jwt.SigningMethodES512`?

Comment: @Woody1193 yes, it is the same: P521 + SHA-512